# Flask. Blueprint. CSS styles are not applied to the page with the form when using the POST method

Tags: css, forms, flask, blueprint

I came across the fact that if, when using Blueprint, a page with a form in blueprint uses CSS styles from the static folder of the application, then when the form is first opened, the styles are pulled up, but if the POST method is added to the form url handler and an action = URL handler of the same form is assigned in the page template, then after sending the form data, the styles are no longer pulling up.

The structure of the application.

```
app-|
    |-static-|
    |        |-main.css
    |
    |-Templates-|
    |           |-base_adm.html
    |
    |-main-|
    |      |-Templates-|
    |      |           |-login_form.html
    |      |
    |      |-__init__.py
    |
    |-__init__.py
```

_

```
# /app/__init__.py

from flask import Flask
...
app = Flask(__name__)
...
from .main import main as main_blp
app.register_blueprint(main_blp, url_prefix='')
```

_

```
# /app/templates/base_adm.html

<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{{ the_title }}</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/main.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
    ...
{% block body %}

{% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

_

```
# /app/main/__init__.py

from flask import Blueprint, render_template
    
main = Blueprint('main', __name__, template_folder='templates') 

@main.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    return render_template('login_form.html', message='Hello')
```

_

```
# /app/main/templates/login_form.html

{% extends 'base_adm.html' %}

{% block body %}

<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<form method='POST' name="add" action={{ url_for(".login") }}>
    <div class="div_nav1">
        <input class='input_filtr' name='user' type='TEXT' value='' placeholder="Login" size="3">
    </div>
    <div class="div_nav1">
        <input class='input_filtr' name='password' type='TEXT' value="" placeholder="Password" size="50">
    </div>
    <div class="div_float">
        <input class='form_button' name='button_add' value='Enter' type='SUBMIT'>
    </div>
    <div class="div_float">
        <input class='form_button' value='Clear' type='Reset'>
    </div>
</form>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>

{{ message }}

{% endblock %}
```

If you look at the page code, then when styles fly off, an error appears:

GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/main.css
[HTTP/1.1 405 METHOD NOT ALLOWED 3ms]

As a result , if in **/app/main/init.py** add to login() getting the value of a form field:

```
user_name = request.form.get('user', '')
```

then the styles stop flying off. I don't understand how this is connected. Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a relative path to the stylesheet

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/main.css" />
```

use an absolute path

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/main.css" />
```

or better, let Flask do it for you

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='main.css') }}" />
```

Comment: I also set the path using url_for, but it didn't help. It is the appeal to the form data that helps. This is incomprehensible to me.

Comment: Start up your application, and before doing anything else, make a request by hand (using `curl` or `wget`) to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/main.css`.  What happens?